# Rigify torso deformity when I parent the generated rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

Whenever I parent the generated rig the my mesh there is always a the same torso deformity I have tried moving the bones and regenerating it. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First thing, display the deforming bones of the armature called *rig*:

[image]

Then shift select the object, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select a bone of the lower arm, as you see the weight paint is not good, it influences the hips:

[image]

You need to correct that in *Weight Paint* mode, or give your armature and object a default T pose, and reparent *With Automatic Weights* to see if the result is better.